# Prove that x is an eigenvector of C, and find the eigenvalue of C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let *A*, *B* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be invertible matrices
>   admitting a common eigenvector ***x*** $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$, where *A*
>   ***x*** = $\lambda$***x*** and *B* ***x*** = $\mu$***x*** for $\lambda$, $\mu$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.  Prove that ***x*** is an
>   eigenvector of *C* = *A*$^3$*B*$^2$ + 7 *A*$^{-3}$*B*$^{-1}$ - 5
>   *I*$_n$, and find the eigenvalue of *C* to which ***x*** is associated.

I don't even know how to start this... I tried plugging in *A* and *B*'s respective values $\lambda$ and $\mu$ but I'm not even sure what to do after that or if that's how I should go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to show that $Cx = \alpha x$ holds with a certain $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. So we just multiply and look what we get:

\begin{align}
Cx &= A^3 B^2 x + 7A^{-3}B^{-1}x - 5I_nx \\
&= \lambda^3 \mu^2x + 7 \lambda^{-3} \mu^{-1}x - 5x \\
&= (\lambda^3 \mu^2 + 7\lambda^{-3}\mu^{-1} - 5) x.
\end{align}

This shows that $x$ is an eigenvector of $C$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\alpha := \lambda^3 \mu^2 + 7\lambda^{-3}\mu^{-1} - 5$. Here, $\lambda^{-3}$ and $\mu^{-1}$ exist due to the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Note that I have used here rules for eigenvectors of powers of matrices, like: If $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\mu$, then $x$ is an eigenvector of $B^2$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\mu^2$.

Comment: Wow, that's really simple, I guess I was overthinking it.. Thank you so much! So is this as far as we can get in finding C's eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, you can't say more here. But if you know the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, then you can calculate the one of $C$ directly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A and B are invertibles means that $\lambda≠0\ and\ \mu≠0$
Then By a simple Calculus you can show that :
$$Cx=A^3(B^2x)+7A^{-3}(B^{-1}x)-5x=\mu^2A^3x+\frac{7}{\mu}A^{-3}x-5x$$
Finley we have :
$$Cx=\biggl(\mu^2\lambda^3+\frac{7}{\mu\lambda^3}-5\biggr)x$$